# C++ Boost awaitable not recognized

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, boost-asio

I'm trying to use **awaitable** from `boost::asio::awaitable` but is not recognized

> error: ‘boost::asio::awaitable’ has not been declared

Even though I have **Boost 1.71** and I'm using on Ubuntu 19.04

```
#include <boost/asio/awaitable.hpp>   //<---- it's working 

boost::asio::awaitable<void> something(){   //<---- error: it's not able to see awaitable

}
```

here it's my CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(Project)

message(STATUS "start running cmake...")


set(BOOST_ROOT "boost_1_71_0")
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS "boost_1_71_0")
set(Boost_LIBRARIES "boost_1_71_0/stage/lib")
set(BOOST_SYSTEM "boost_1_71_0/stage/lib/libboost_system.so")
set(BOOST_FILE_SYSTEM "boost_1_71_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.so")


find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system thread)

message(STATUS "Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "Boost_LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
message(STATUS "Boost_VERSION: ${Boost_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "BOOST_SYSTEM: ${BOOST_SYSTEM}")
message(STATUS "BOOST_FILE_SYSTEM: ${BOOST_FILE_SYSTEM}")

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(ServerMain Plugins/PluginInterface.h Plugins/PluginBinary.cpp Plugins/PluginBinary.h Plugins/PluginString.cpp Plugins/PluginString.h Server/Server.cpp Server/Server.h Server/ServerMain.cpp Server/Session.cpp Server/Session.h)
add_executable(ClientMain Client/Client.cpp Client/Client.h Client/ClientMain.cpp Client/Utils.h)

target_link_libraries(ServerMain ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(ClientMain ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

target_link_libraries(ServerMain ${BOOST_FILE_SYSTEM} ${BOOST_SYSTEM} pthread)
target_link_libraries(ClientMain ${BOOST_FILE_SYSTEM} ${BOOST_SYSTEM} pthread)
```

Also, I'm using **C++17**.

Any idea how can I make this work?

Comment: G++ doesnt support coroutines yet. But on Windows, you can try to compile this with MSVC with '/await'  flag.

Answer (score 0):

you should use clang++, since gcc 7/8/9 doesn't support coroutine ts so fa.

Answer (score 0):

check asio(boost asio standalone) fork version of mine (echo_server build fine):

https://github.com/sailfish009/asio

Note: [latest clang++](https://github.com/sailfish009/llvm_all) required